# How to Reset PostgreSQL on Windows 11

Tags: postgresql

I uninstalled PostgreSQL 14 on my Windows 11 laptop and installed PostgreSQL 12. For some reason, I can't log into my server or create a database. I keep getting this error: "connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"".  I tried using my old and new passwords that I created when I uninstalled and reinstalled PostgreSQL (I had to uninstall and reinstall PostgreSQL 14 once more before deciding to switch to an older version so that I could get XAMPP to work), but I just keep getting the same error. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: IIRC different postgres versions have different data and configuration files, so the user and login methods you created for v14 do not apply to v12 - you'll need to do that again.

Comment: Look in the db server's log file to see if there are more details on the failure.  The message sent to the unauthenticated client is intentionally vague to avoid disclosing info to hostile parties.

Answer (score -2):

Try to delete `C:\Users\<user>\Documents\postgresdata`